# Retrieve all the file paths from a QDropEvent

Tags: qt

I implemented drag and drop in my software. Basically I've got a QTableView which contains file paths. The user must be able to just drag and drop files in the QTableView in order to add them.

I've already done the big of the job but I'm stuck in iterating all the paths contained in the QDropEvent object. I have to implement the `dropEvent` method.

```
void Generous::dropEvent(QDropEvent *dropEvent) {
    QStringList filePathList;

    // Way to iterate dropEvent and append each file path to filePathList.

    addFilesToListView(filePathList);
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that a drag and drop using *filepaths* use the MIME type `text/uri-list`.

If this is true, you should probably be able to retrieve the data like this:

```
if (dropEvent->mimeData()->hasUrls())
{
    foreach (QUrl url, dropEvent->mimeData()->urls())
    {
        filePathList << url.toLocalFile();
    }
}
```

Anyway, since I am not sure, the best would be first to check what kind of info is stored inside the drop event, and see where and how you can extract the filepaths:

```
QStringList availableMimeTypes = dropEvent->mimeData()->formats();
qDebug() << "available MIME types:" << dropEvent->mimeData()->formats() << "\n";

foreach(QString mimeType, availableMimeTypes)
{
    qDebug() << "data for MIME type" << mimeType << " :";
    qDebug() << dropEvent->mimeData()->data(mimeType) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a global list that will keep appending the filePaths on each dropevent. So at the end you will be having a complete list of paths.